# Need help achieving a hover animation effect

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm currently working on a hover animation and aiming to achieve the following effect:
[Link to expected animation](https://www.loom.com/share/a46631d72f3c45609e09e980b997ea77?sid=8d0c40f8-5620-4f86-ac2f-db6cb1033f26)

I've created a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/border-animation-6s92p7?file=/index.html) to demonstrate my current approach.

Assets used in this animation can be [found here](https://www.figma.com/file/W3xxE7fzz1xmbUq9k9Aump/Card-hover-animation?type=design&node-id=0%3A1&mode=design&t=B2HpZV68eZCY7ZVB-1).

I'm open to any suggestions or improvements on the hover animation. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I am having hard time controlling the cycle of the animation.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="wrap"></div>
  </div>
</div>

body {
  background: #000;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}
.card {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: #2c2c2c;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -2px;
  top: -2px;
  background-image: url("./bg-2.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: calc(100% + 4px);
  height: calc(100% + 4px);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
}

.card:hover::before {
  animation: clippath 0.9s linear forwards;
}

.card:not(:hover)::before {
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background-image: url("./bg-1.png");
}

.wrap {
  background: #2c2c2c;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 200px;
}

@keyframes clippath {
  0%,
  100% {
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
    clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 98% 0 0);
    clip-path: inset(0 0 0 98%);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(98% 0 0 0);
    clip-path: inset(98% 0 0 0);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 0 0 98%);
    clip-path: inset(0 98% 0 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should explain what is wrong with the current approach and create a [mre] right within your question. Read: [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a faded border effect using background linear gradient. Set two gradients up, one to overlap the other. The top one is the button colour. The bottom one is the effect you're trying to achieve. Position the backgrounds using padding box and border box respectively so that the background with the fade goes all the way to the border edge.

You can then use the [fairly recent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property) `@property` rule to animate the background. This isn't [fully supported yet](https://caniuse.com/?search=%40property) but has pretty good coverage apart from Firefox. It cut out a lot of CSS though. See below.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

@property --angle {
  syntax: '<angle>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 135deg;
}

.button {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 12rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  background-color: #2c2c2c;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #2c2c2c, #2c2c2c), 
              linear-gradient(var(--angle), gray 10%, transparent 30%, transparent 70%, gray 100%);
  border: 0.5rem solid transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box,
                   border-box;
  background-origin: padding-box,
                     border-box;
  transition: --angle 250ms;
}

.button:hover {
  --angle: 45deg;
}
```

```html
<div class='button'>Some text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with css using background gradient and animating the same on hover.

```css
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
   background: #000;
   padding: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
   margin: auto;
}
.card {
   z-index: 1;
   height: 200px;
   position: relative;
   background: #2c2c2c;
   border-radius: 8px;
   cursor: pointer;
   overflow: hidden;

   &:hover:before {
      transform: rotate(180deg);
   }

   &::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      background: #2c2c2c;
      border-radius: 8px;
      left: 2px;
      right: 2px;
      top: 2px;
      bottom: 2px;
   }

   &::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: -2px;
      top: -2px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: calc(100% + 4px);
      height: calc(100% + 4px);
      z-index: -1;
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      background: linear-gradient(
         142deg,
         rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%,
         rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 20%,
         rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 80%,
         rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
      );
      border-radius: 8px;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="card">
      <div class="wrap"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```